# How to retrieve the Id of a newly Posted entity using ASP.Net Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, system.text.json, system.net.http.json

I `Post` a new `Waste` entity using the following code:

```
var result = await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(wasteApiRoute, waste);
```

The Api Controller (using the code created by VS) seems to try to make life easy for me by sending back the new Id of the `Waste` entity using:

```
 return CreatedAtAction("GetWaste", new { id = waste.Id }, waste);
```

So the `result`variable wil contain this data. Indeed, I find it in its `Headers.Location` property as an url.

But how do I nicely extract the Id property from the result without resorting to regular expressions and the like? Surely the creators of ASP.Net Core will have included a nifty call for that?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the best I can come up with is:

```
 var result = await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(wasteApiRoute, waste);
 var newWaste = await result.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<Waste>();
```

Where `waste` has an Id of zero, `newWaste` has its Id set.